# Js regexp: How to extract special substring ?

Tags: javascript, regex

My code sample is as the following:

```
    let str = '<p>test xss<img src=x onerror=alert(1)><h1 onmouseover=prompt(0)></h1></p>';

    console.log(str.replace(/(<img [\s\S]*>?|<h1 [\s\S]*><\/h1>)/i, ''));
```

My purpose is very clear: extract `img` and `h1` tag from `str`, so I expect the result is `<p>test xss</p>`, but actually the result is `<p>test xss`. It seems the regexp string img judgement part match the end of str. Can anyone tell me how to write this regexp string correctly ?

Comment: regexp on html "strings" are [notorious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5053002)

Comment: I'd suggest using DOMParser, but it's going to mess with the `h1` inside the `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my regexp rule to `/(<img [\s\S]*?>|<h1[\s\S]*\/h1>)/ig` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little incomplete code, but just to give an example. Try something like this

```
let parser = new DOMParser()
let doc = parser.parseFromString(parser, "text/html")
```

and then you can operate on the `doc` like a HTMLDocument Node, with `querySelectorAll` and stuff

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
'<p>test xss<img src=x onerror=alert(1)><h1 onmouseover=prompt(0)></h1></p>'.replace(/<p>([\w ]+)\b.*<\/p>/, '<p>$1</p>')
```

?